# Laravel mix styles

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.3

I´m using Laravel 5.3, and I want mix my styles in other file name, when I run gulp --production, this works fine if the public/css/ file is called "all.css":

```
mix.styles([
    'public/css/vendor/normalize.css',
    'public/css/vendor/videojs.css'
], 'public/css/all.css');
```

But, if I change the all.css name by: finalstyles.css for example:

```
mix.styles([
    'public/css/vendor/normalize.css',
    'public/css/vendor/videojs.css'
], 'public/css/finalstyles.css');
```

This not works for me, and gulp not throw errors.

How to fix this?

Comment: did you check you scripts tag?

Comment: ??? I´m not usign script tag, I only use  <link href="{{ FuImg::asset('css/finalstyles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">